# How to change the following sentence to reported speech?

Tags: passive-voice

How to change the following sentence to reported speech??

The mother said to the girl,"This is how you make a pizza."

Comment: Since this is ELU, please forgive a nit-picking digression. You should note that two adjacent question marks are incorrect. I'm a bit uncomfortable about that comma too. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The comma would have been seen as essential 50 years ago. Now, it is optional before a quote; I use a colon, a comma or zero punctuation as I feel is appropriate in any given case. Here, I'd omit the comma, unless I wanted to convey a dramatic pause (eg marking exasperation with the person being spoken to).

Comment: I don't think that there's a close enough indirect speech alternative. Phil M Jones's answer works if and only if the mother's words follow the demonstration. 'The girl's mother showed the girl how to make a pizza, telling her exactly what the demonstration was about.' Stick with direct speech.

Comment: You could replace *said* in the direct speech to *told* in the indirect to simplify: "The mother **told** the girl that was how a pizza is made." -- avoids '*that that*' and the '*you*' which is misleading (it was not a reference to the girl).

Comment: @Elian has a point there. Why was the answer deleted? I actually tried to up vote it before realizing it's just been deleted.

Comment: There is no "passive voice" in your example, and so you'd probably want to delete that tag from your post.

Answer (score 1):

The mother said to the girl that that was how you make a pizza.

Comment: +1 but a construction that is more acceptable spoken than written?

Comment: True, but carrying down the *you* could be confusing to an ESL student.

Answer (score -1):

> The mother told the girl that was how one makes a pizza.

Or

> The mother told the girl that was how a pizza is made.

Answer (score -1):

> The  mother told the girl how to make a pizza.

Answer (score -2):

The mother told the girl that that was how she made a pizza.

Comment: And why is this better than the multiple existing answers?